# Letsencrypt + HAProxy SSL Offloading

Tags: haproxy, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am using HAProxy for SSL offloading and letsencrypt certificates.  Previously, I was using the tls-sni-01-port flag - which is no longer supported.

Does anyone have a recipe that has been working in this configuration?